# Are there flapper discs designed for cleaning fiberglass/plastic rather than metal?

Tags: cleaning, angle-grinder, grinder, flapper-disc, abrasives

I was cleaning my bathroom the other day and while I was trying to scrub out various bits of scum and buildup I started wondering if this was something my angle grinder could do for me. My obvious concern is that it will be too powerful and cut a hole in my shower’s fiberglass walls or strip away the silicon sealant on the outside edges.

Does anyone know if this is something that can be done without damaging anything if I use the right kind of wheel?

Comment: Here's something for a drill: https://www.amazon.com/Bathroom-Accessories-Cleaning-Supplies-Porcelain/dp/B00I8YDVD8/. A grinder's 13000 RPM doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Porcelain is a lot harder than fiberglass gelcoat or acrylic. Mild acids tend to be the ticket for most "bath scum" without threatening plastic finishes.

Comment: Maybe ask at a boat builder/boat repair shop.  Anything else than a wax buffing wheel probably too rough.

Answer (score 4):

Generally the answer is no, there isn't a mechanical power cleaning method that is safe to use on fiberglass.

It's quite easy to end up damaging the surface of the fiberglass in a way that makes it get dirtier quicker. Once that coating is damaged, the fiberglass will get dirty much more easily than with an undamaged coating. Because of this you want to generally use gentle cleaners on fiberglass, and hand clean only.

Comment: Not only will it get dirty, but it will expose the actual glass fibers and those are... uncomfortable, especially if you get them on your more private bits when showering.

Comment: I was being optimistic that someone would notice scratching in the gel coat before they got all the way down to the fiber.

Comment: I used fiberglass electric fence posts.  After the first year you learnt to use heavy gloves or pliers when touching them.